# Adding a 5 star-rating on rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to add 5 star rating in my rails 4 application. Most of the resources out there requires a user model. My case is different. I'm targeting site visitors with no sort of authentication for them to vote. I'd wish site visitors to vote for courses.

Here's part of my course model(course.rb)

```
has_many :ratings
```

Then rating.rb

```
belongs_to :course
```

I'd wish to add to a rating link on index page for all the courses i.e index method on course_controller ought to handle the voting. Of course I might need to make use of ratings controller. I just can't pull it off right. And idea how I should go about it? A detailed answer would be appreciated. Much of what I've done so far has been based on this tutorial http://paweljaniak.co.za/2013/07/25/5-star-ratings-with-rails/ though I still haven't been successful.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to add a column to the `Rating` table so that ratings know which course they belong to.

```
rails generate migration add_course_reference_to_ratings course:references score:integer default: 0
```

You'll notice in the migration the default score is an integer of `0`.

Migrate your database `rake db:migrate`

Your ratings need routes, but your rating should only needing the `update` action:

```
resources :ratings, only: :update
```

In your course controller add the following to what you already have in your `index` action:

```
def index
  @rating = Rating.where(comment_id: @comment.id).first
  unless @rating
    @rating = Rating.create(comment_id: @comment.id, score: 0)
  end
end
```

The view and JavaScript stuff on that tutorial should work fine. Note that you aren't validating against logged in users so there isn't anything stopping people from sending unlimited ratings affecting the average.

Comment: Note that the JavaScript in the tutorial makes use of `@commment` - you should obviously change to `@course` where necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately the ratings aren't loaded on the views and neither can visitors rate yet there're no errors. I just have  the placeholders, blank Averate rating & Your rating. Everything is set. @Simpleton I downloaded the jquery.raty.min.js from the raty site and added this to my application.js //= require jquery.raty.min.js. For your case you've used raty.min.js which I couldn't find.

Comment: I have come across the same problem, I cannot get it to display either